# linq select sum and average into view model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

How can I do this in a single select statement?

```
var data = new CampaignData()
{
    TotalPost = await context.Campaigns.SumAsync(c => c.Posts),
    AveragePost = await context.Campaigns.AverageAsync(c => c.Posts),
    TotalImpression = await context.Campaigns.SumAsync(c => c.Impressions),
    AverageImpressions = await context.Campaigns.AverageAsync(c => c.Impressions),
};
```

Comment: I imagine you can't.

Comment: why not? I can do with a single line in sql.

Comment: Because I can't think of any "automatic" way to do all of that with a single enumeration (which is basically what you are asking for). You could do it manually of course, but... ugly. The tradeoff isn't worth it unless your collection is very large.

Comment: there is an ugly way of doing something similar using 1 query but looks like we cannot use `Async` methods with that. Possibly you can try making some other async method to fetch all the data (instead of using each Async). Then you can use the approach I mentioned.

Comment: Seriously this simple query can't be done in linq??? .. Stored procedure it is then :( 

select count(*) as Posts, AVG(cast(Posts as float)) as AveragePosts, SUM(Impressions) as TotalImpressions, AVG(cast(reach as float)) as AverageDailyReach, AVG(cast(AverageFrequency as float)) as AverageDailyFrequency
  from dbo.Campaigns

Comment: @MIKE: right now the above 4 lines of code are running (sorta) asynchronously. Not sure why it's `awaiting` 4 times, a single thread jump is all you really need. But the general concept is sound, which is to divide up one complex query, into smaller, faster executing parts, and then merge the results back. Why would you want to go back to the complex query? I'd be focused on optimizing those `awaits` and seeing if some of those thread jumps are truly necessary.

Comment: @code4life Serious question, async methods return a task. How would I assign a task to int without the compiler complaining? I rather have a complex looking query then have to make 4 db calls on the same table.

Comment: @MIKE: async methods return a task which contain a result, which you can assign to the int...

Comment: @MIKE I've updated my answer with an example of what code4life meant about using one `await` instead of 4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can group by a constant so you can get the sums and averages.  Then use `SingleAsync` to get the single result.

```
var data = await (from compaign in context.Compaigns
                  group compaign by 1 into grp
                  select new CampaignData()
                  {
                      TotalPost = grp.Sum(cc => cc.Posts),
                      AveragePost = grp.Average(c => c.Posts),
                      TotalImpression = grp.Sum(c => c.Impressions),
                      AverageImpressions = grp.Average(c => c.Impressions),
                  }).SingleAsync();
```

Another option is to actually let your asynchronous DB calls run in parallel

```
var totalPostTask = context.Campaigns.SumAsync(c => c.Posts);
var averagePostTask = context.Campaigns.AverageAsync(c => c.Posts);
var totalImpressionTask = context.Campaigns.SumAsync(c => c.Impressions);
var averageImpressionsTask = context.Campaigns.AverageAsync(c => c.Impressions);

await Task.WhenAll(
    totalPostTask, 
    averagePostTask, 
    totalImpressionTask, 
    averageImpressionsTask);

var data = new CampaignData()
{
    TotalPost = totalPostTask.Result,
    AveragePost = averagePostTask.Result,
    TotalImpression = totalImpressionTask.Result,
    AverageImpressions = averageImpressionsTask.Result,
};
```

If I had to guess I'd say the single DB call would perform better, but you can always test both options out to see which is better.

Comment: Only one SingleAsync(), it is realy doing it with one query, but sure looks more complicated. It can't be perfect anyway.

Comment: perfect. Will the group by affect performance? Does it get generated in the sql?

Comment: Will FirstOrDefaultAsync give me the same results? I prefer not to crash with no results.

Comment: @MIKE I'm not sure the exact SQL this will create, but even if it does create a group by clause the DB will likely execute it as if it were not there.  Also you can do `SingleOrDefaultAsync` instead, but I'm pretty sure this will always return exactly one result, even if the table is empty, and it will never return more than one.